# Permissions In Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, permissions

Please am Trying to build a app which it has three user types 1. management 2. staff 3. accountant and the management user want to add and give certain permissions to a user of staff or accountant please help

Models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data = ((1, "management"), (2, "staff"), (3, "finance"))
    user_type = models.CharField(default=1, choices=user_type_data, max_length=10)
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? What do you want and where are you stuck?

Comment: i want the management user to create and assign permissions to the other user_types and i've created the user_types and i can't go further please help

Comment: To follow way you started in your model, to achieve that, you will need views and templates to create a 'page' where the users with management rights can assign the other user a type. I would also suggest taking a look into the built in [permissions in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions)

Comment: thank you don't mean to be lazy but if u have any boilerplate or template please share me the link sorry @DrummerMann

Comment: I'm afraid I do not, The best way to learn is to get started and see where you hit a wall, then you can maybe ask a new question on here where you show your idea and solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.